# How to convert numpy array saved as string in pandas csv file back to a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, csv

I saved with pandas a numpy array to a csv file:

```
df['Feature5'][i] = str(ri_RGBA.tolist())
df.to_csv(r'H:\test.csv')
```

The csv file has the following structure:

```
Feature1,Feature2,Feature3,Feature4,Labels,Feature5
13.37,33.09,-0.08,992.2,nass,"[[1, 160, 246, 255], … ,[1, 160, 246, 255]]"
26.37,33.03,-0.08,992.2,trocken,"[[110, 160, 246, 255], … ,[20, 160, 246, 255]]"
```

Now I'm trying to convert the string "[[1, 160, 246, 255], …" back to a numpy array:

```
data = df['Feature5'].apply(lambda x: 
                           np.fromstring(
                               x.replace('\n','')
                                .replace('"','')
                                .replace('[','')
                                .replace(']','')
                                .replace('  ',' ')
                                .replace(' ',''), sep=','))
```

But `print(data.dtypes)` still returns me type 'object'. What am I missing? Any ideas how I could make this work?

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: with those '...' you can't recover the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get you there.

```
import ast
my_list = ast.literal_eval(df['Feature5'][i])
data = np.array(my_list)
```

Note, that `literal_eval` is horribly unsafe and should not be called with unchecked user input.

On that note: Why do you save your data like that? Numpy arrays are best stored via `np.save` or - if you insist on human-readable csv - as a column in your dataframe like that:

`df['Feature5'] = pd.Series(data)`

If your data is actual RGBA image data, I would suggest to save the images as PNGs or numpy arrays via `np.save` and just storing a filename in the csv.
Your approach is slow, fragile, hard to understand and hard to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. That seems to work. I will update my question. Not sure how stackoverflow works. But I can't really reply in the comment with a long answer.

Comment: Hi, this looks like a new problem. You should have only one problem per question on SO, so other people can search for similar problems and get specific solutions. It'd be best, if you open a new question for your new problem.